# How to Create boxes on images JtessBoxEditor?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, ocr, tesseract, training-data

I need to retrain tesseract, therefore I am using, JtessboxEditor. However it does not create boxes on images.

I found this question on the StackOverFlow however it does not solve my problem.
[How to generate a tiff/box file from an image to train Tesseract in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31751402/how-to-generate-a-tiff-box-file-from-an-image-to-train-tesseract-in-windows)

I did what the answers suggest, however still I cannot create boxes on images.

Here is the error I get:

```
How can I create boxes ? 

Any help is appreciated. Thank you very much.
Error opening data file C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\eng.traineddata
 Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to your "tessdata" directory.
 Failed loading language 'eng' Tesseract couldn't load any languages! Could not initialize tesseract
```

Answer (score 0):

JTessBoxEditor can only support training for legacy Tesseract 3.x. You probably has Tesseract 4.x installed on your machine; `TESSDATA_PREFIX` variable points to `tessdata` of that version, which is incompatible with JTessboxEditor training.

Comment: I am using Tesseract 3.x